# Set JavaScript as the language hint for [unityscript]

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

It would be nice if the JavaScript syntax highlighting could be applied to the [unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) tag.

I know I can enable it for individual posts, but the tag should default to the JavaScript syntax highlighting.

Comment: Note: The syntax highlighter [was changed in September 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter).

Answer (score 4):

Just pulling in some Unity script from [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29082843) to see what it looks like (forcing the syntax highlighting with `<!-- language: lang-js -->`):

```js
@script RequireComponent(MeshFilter)
@script RequireComponent(MeshRenderer)
private    var matarray : Material[] = new Material[2];
var mat : Material;
var mat2 : Material;

function Start () {
    matarray[0] = mat;
    matarray[1] = mat2;

    for (var child in transform)
        child.position += transform.position;
    transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

    var meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren(MeshFilter);
    var combine : CombineInstance[] = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length-1];
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < meshFilters.Length; i++) {
        if (meshFilters[i].sharedMesh == null)
            continue;
        combine[index].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
        combine[index++].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        renderer.sharedMaterials = matarray;
        meshFilters[i].active = false;
    }
    GetComponent(MeshFilter).mesh = new Mesh();
    GetComponent(MeshFilter).mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
    renderer.active = true;

    //Here seems to be the trouble.
    renderer.sharedMaterials = matarray;
}
```

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not a JS guy... and certainly not unityscript. The thing is more of "get a bunch of code, stick it in there and let people look at it".  With out it people are saying "I think it will look good" or "I don't think it will look good" without any basis than what is in their head.  Please feel free to edit and adjust to make it a more useful demonstration.  I was just after a sufficiently large set of different language expressions in one block of code.

Answer (score -6):

Why? UnityScript is nothing like JavaScript. The syntaxes are completely different.

If you want a UnityScript syntax highlighter then ask for that feature, but asking for UnityScript to be highlighted by the JavaScript highlighter is just wrong when the two languages are not even close to having compatible syntaxes.

Comment: AFAIK the syntax highlighting is done by Google Code Prettify, so requesting support for a new language had to be directed to them and I guess they will just not care. The JavaScript syntax highlighting should be close enough to give a better experience than no syntax highlighting at all

Comment: Have you tried asking? Or for that matter submitting a patch? [It doesn't look that hard to add one](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc)

Comment: I don't know much about UnityScript or JavaScript, in fact I never coded anything with them. I took a look at this [comparison](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) and I still can't see in which way it would matter for syntax highlighting. Keywords seem to be the same or even less, regex are missing too, so the JavaScript syntax highlighting should work just fine.

Comment: The 2 are different languages and will progress in different paths, they should be separate files. As a simple example of a difference, types are supposed to be marked separately. There are no types in JavaScript though except possibly when you say `new Type()` whereas in UnityScript you can put a type after any function or variable as in `var foo : someType` or `function() : someType`. That means the 2 languages need different rules to figure out where the types are so they can apply the right styles. They aren't the same.

Comment: You expect too much from Google Code Prettify. It doesn't understand the language, it basically marks keywords, strings and types. Types are simply identified either by a fixed list or by using a simple regex that matches words beginning with a capital letter. Just look at the results of the JavaScript syntax highlighting applied to UnityScript: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24115666/3517635), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24228094/3517635) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24068577/3517635). It just works!

Comment: And yes it's not flawless, but the same applies to C# for example. Not everything is recognized correctly, precisely because it doesn't understand the language and only uses simply rules to apply syntax highlighting.

Comment: You could argue about all the specific implementations of SQL not covering all bases, it doesn't matter though, there's enough similarities to warrant this change. It will only improve them, so why not?

Comment: Because they are not even remotely close to the same language. The only reason you think they are is because Unity originally called it JavaScript. UnityScript has absolutely ZERO to do with JavaScript. They're completely different languages not related to each other in the least. This isn't like variants of SQL. UnityScript is not related to JavaScript at all. Note: I went ahead and [submitted a patch to support unityscript in google's code prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=345&sort=-id)

Comment: The JS highlighting works reasonably well for UnityScript anyway, which is the only thing that matters.

Comment: Btw that argument SO should get rid of a bunch of other highliters because there are others that are close enough. Either do it right or don't do it at all. Sheesh