# Please enable syntax-highlighting for [UnityScript]

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

[unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) is the scripting-language used in unity3d.

Because it currently has no syntax-highlighting-hint, people are mis-tagging JavaScript, misusing stack-snippets or do other weird things to get some hopefully appropriate-looking highlighting.

Can we please just enable it to discourage those desparate workarounds?

`lang-js` should work due to similarities.
`default` might be better for avoiding clashes with the host-programs language, but I don't think they are that prevalent...

Comment: There is a [google-code-prettify request](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=345&sort=-id) and a previoux [meta request to apply javascript syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254526/set-javascript-as-language-hint-for-unityscript). See also [UnityScript syntax highlighting for Sublime Text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Unity3D).